# Not understanding why this won't sum up properly

Tags: python

```
grades = [100, 100, 90, 40, 80, 100, 85, 70, 90, 65, 90, 85, 50.5]

def grades_sum(grades):
    sum = 0
    for i in grades:
        sum += grades[i]
print(grades_sum(grades))
```

That's my code and I'm trying to understand why I'm getting an out of index traceback.

Comment: I think you will find that this method of doing for loops is more useful and less bug prone than the traditional C-style for loop where you use an index variable, etc... (think about whether there could be something even more useful than this method though)

Comment: You should not name your variable `sum`, because that's the name of a built-in function, and it can lead to confusion.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't need to do `grade[i]` because you're already referencing the elements in the list - all you need to do it replace that with a plain old `i`

However, there is already a builtin function for this - `sum`

```
print(sum(grades))
```

Comment: Thank you! Assignment told me to avoid using sum().

Answer (score 14):

Iterating over a list will return the item in the list, not the index of the item. The correct code as you have written it would look like this:

```
def grades_sum(grades):
    total = 0
    for grade in grades:
        total += grade 
    return total
```

Of course as others have answered this can be done much more elegant using [`sum`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum).

If you actually need the index for something else you could use [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate) like this:

```
def grades_sum(grades):
    total = 0
    for i, grade in enumerate(grades):
        total += grade #or grades[i] 
    return total
```

Or if you don't care about retrieving the item at all

```
def grades_sum(grades):
    total = 0
    for i in range(len(grades)):
        total += grades[i] 
    return total
```

Comment: less confusing if you do not use the variable name `sum` (as the OP did) just to introduce the Python function `sum`

Answer (score 6):

`for i in grades:` iterates over the elements in `grades`. It doesn't iterate over the indexes.

To fix your code, just use `i` instead of `grades[i]`.

Don't be afraid of using `print` statements. They're excellent for debugging code.